# How to convert int[] to byte[]

Tags: java, arrays, type-conversion

I have an array of integers which represent a RGB image and would like to convert it to a byte array and save it to a file.

What's the best way to convert an array of integers to the array of bytes in Java?

Comment: Maybe you will get better and more pointed answers if you mention reasons why you choose to convert int[] to byte[].

Answer (score 72, accepted):

As [Brian](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1086067/1536976) says, you need to work out how what sort of conversion you need.

Do you want to save it as a "normal" image file (jpg, png etc)?

If so, you should probably use the [Java Image I/O](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/imageio/) API.

If you want to save it in a "raw" format, the order in which to write the bytes must be specified, and then use an `IntBuffer` and NIO.

As an example of using a ByteBuffer/IntBuffer combination:

```
import java.nio.*;
import java.net.*;

class Test
{   
    public static void main(String [] args)
        throws Exception // Just for simplicity!
    {
        int[] data = { 100, 200, 300, 400 };

        ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(data.length * 4);        
        IntBuffer intBuffer = byteBuffer.asIntBuffer();
        intBuffer.put(data);

        byte[] array = byteBuffer.array();

        for (int i=0; i < array.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(i + ": " + array[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

Maybe use this method

```
byte[] integersToBytes(int[] values)
{
   ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
   DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(baos);
   for(int i=0; i < values.length; ++i)
   {
        dos.writeInt(values[i]);
   }

   return baos.toByteArray();
}
```

Comment: this will split int to byte. i dont think this is what in need.

Comment: he wants to save it to a file for later use, so this would be suitable

Comment: Why do you wrap `baos` inside `dos`?

Answer (score 3):

You need to decide how you convert 1 integer to a set of bytes first.

Most probably (?) 1 integer to 4 bytes, and use the shift (`>>` or `<<`) operators to get each byte out (watch that byte ordering!). Copy to a byte array 4 times the length of the integer array.

Answer (score 2):

if your intent is to save to file you maybe want to save directly in a file using FileOutputStream.write:

```
    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("aa");
    int[] rgb = { 0xff, 0xff, 0xff };
    for (int c : rgb) {
        os.write(c);
    }
    os.close();
```

since it:

> Writes the specified byte to this output stream. The general contract for write is that one byte is written to the output stream. The byte to be written is the eight low-order bits of  the argument b. The 24 high-order bits of b are ignored.

Answer (score 1):

I created this code and it's working pretty well:

```
    int IntToByte(byte arrayDst[], int arrayOrg[], int maxOrg){
        int i;
        int idxDst;
        int maxDst;
        //
        maxDst = maxOrg*4;
        //
        if (arrayDst==null)
            return 0;
        if (arrayOrg==null)
            return 0;
        if (arrayDst.length < maxDst)
            return 0;
        if (arrayOrg.length < maxOrg)
            return 0;
        //
        idxDst = 0;
        for (i=0; i<maxOrg; i++){
            // Copia o int, byte a byte.
            arrayDst[idxDst] = (byte)(arrayOrg[i]);
            idxDst++;
            arrayDst[idxDst] = (byte)(arrayOrg[i] >> 8);
            idxDst++;
            arrayDst[idxDst] = (byte)(arrayOrg[i] >> 16);
            idxDst++;
            arrayDst[idxDst] = (byte)(arrayOrg[i] >> 24);
            idxDst++;
        }
        //
        return idxDst;
    }

    int ByteToInt(int arrayDst[], byte arrayOrg[], int maxOrg){
        int i;
        int v;
        int idxOrg;
        int maxDst;
        //
        maxDst = maxOrg/4;
        //
        if (arrayDst==null)
            return 0;
        if (arrayOrg==null)
            return 0;
        if (arrayDst.length < maxDst)
            return 0;
        if (arrayOrg.length < maxOrg)
            return 0;
        //
        idxOrg = 0;
        for (i=0; i<maxDst; i++){
            arrayDst[i] = 0;
            //
            v = 0x000000FF & arrayOrg[idxOrg];
            arrayDst[i] = arrayDst[i] | v;
            idxOrg++;
            //
            v = 0x000000FF & arrayOrg[idxOrg];
            arrayDst[i] = arrayDst[i] | (v << 8);
            idxOrg++;
            //
            v = 0x000000FF & arrayOrg[idxOrg];
            arrayDst[i] = arrayDst[i] | (v << 16);
            idxOrg++;
            //
            v = 0x000000FF & arrayOrg[idxOrg];
            arrayDst[i] = arrayDst[i] | (v << 24);
            idxOrg++;
        }
        //
        return maxDst;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use 'DataOutputStream' with 'ByteArrayOutputStream'.

```
public final class Converter {

    private static final int BYTES_IN_INT = 4;

    private Converter() {}

    public static byte [] convert(int [] array) {
        if (isEmpty(array)) {
            return new byte[0];
        }

        return writeInts(array);
    }

    public static int [] convert(byte [] array) {
        if (isEmpty(array)) {
            return new int[0];
        }

        return readInts(array);
    }

    private static byte [] writeInts(int [] array) {
        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(array.length * 4);
            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(bos);
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                dos.writeInt(array[i]);
            }

            return bos.toByteArray();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    private static int [] readInts(byte [] array) {
        try {
            ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(array);
            DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(bis);
            int size = array.length / BYTES_IN_INT;
            int[] res = new int[size];
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                res[i] = dataInputStream.readInt();
            }
            return res;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}

    public class ConverterTest {

    @Test
    public void convert() {
        final int [] array = {-1000000, 24000, -1, 40};
        byte [] bytes = Converter.convert(array);
        int [] array2 = Converter.convert(bytes);

        assertTrue(ArrayUtils.equals(array, array2));

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bytes));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array2));
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
[-1000000, 24000, -1, 40]
[-1, -16, -67, -64, 0, 0, 93, -64, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 40]
[-1000000, 24000, -1, 40]
```

Comment: This is almost exactly the same as in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1086071 (the only difference I see is your inital value for the `ByteArrayOutputStream`). Can you explain how this answer adds new information?

Comment: Just refactoring.

Answer (score -1):

```java
  /** int[] --> byte[] */
  private byte[] toByte(int[] data) throws IOException {
    
    byte[] bytes = new byte[data.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
      bytes[i] = (byte) data[i];
    }
    return bytes;
  }
```

really simple ？？？