# How do I declare an array of bytes in Java?

Tags: java, delphi

I have an algorithm written in Delphi and ask me to convert that to java equivalent.

It has a line of code that I can't understand, could anyone help me convert this line of code to java ?!

```
const list: array [1..37] of byte=(9,7,5,3,1,2,4,6,8,4,7,3,9,1,6,5,1,6,7,2,3,6,5,3,8,9,2,1,7,4,2,3,1,9,7,6,8);
```

Comment: Err, and what have you tried ? I bet that if you'd Google for how to construct array in Java you would find the answer. This sounds like a homework of a lazy student.

Comment: If you don't understand that trivial line of pascal you need to stop and do some learning. You won't be able to understand the rest of the code either.

Comment: @TLama @david-heffernan because of my bad english i coudn't explain my main problem, i am programming for more than 3 years in c++ c# and java. that algorithm does encode some data and has a block of code that convert some integer and string value to byte array and i think this line of code do that work , i was wrong , i found a  solution [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19252022/3263370) `here`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you will need to import Collection framework by declaring `import java.util.*;`

```
    byte data [] = {9,7,5,3,1,2,4,6,8,4,7,3,9,1,6,5,1,6,7,2,3,6,5,3,8,9,2,1,7,4,2,3,1,9,7,6,8};
    List<byte[]> list = new ArrayList<byte[]>(Arrays.asList(data));

    // outputting your data
    for(byte [] arrayOfByte : list){
    for( byte element : arrayOfByte){
    System.out.println(element);
    }
   }
```

If you don't want to use collection Framework then , simply :

```
    byte list [] = {9,7,5,3,1,2,4,6,8,4,7,3,9,1,6,5,1,6,7,2,3,6,5,3,8,9,2,1,7,4,2,3,1,9,7,6,8};
```