# Java / Android - How to convert int array into smallest byte array?

Tags: java, android, arrays, type-conversion, nfc

I need to convert an int array like this...

```
int[] myInts = {
    99999,
    9999,
    99999,
    1,
    1234567890,
    24385933,
    99
};
```

...as efficiently as possible into a `byte[]` so it can be saved on an NFC tag.

I have seen [this very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086054/how-to-convert-int-to-byte) from which I have tried the two the answers ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1086092/1617737) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1086071/1617737)), but the byte arrays they create both have a length of 28.

Unfortunately, that's no good for me as **I need to create a byte[] with a maximum length of 16** (as the tag this data has to be saved on is a MIFARE Ultralight EV1).

Is there any other approach I could try in order to convert `myInts` to a `byte[16]`?

Comment: Each integer is 4 bytes. 7 x 4 = 28, the only way is if you know that some of those values are <=255 in which you could use 1 byte for that value.

Comment: Do you have any known constraints on the values of the array? For example, if you know that some of the elements of the array are within the range -128 to 127, you can store them in a single byte instead of 4 bytes.

Comment: The only way you can mathematically even hope to do this is if you can prove there are fewer than 2^(8 * 16)=2^128 possibilities for arrays you'll need to compress.  If that's not possible, you're 100% out of luck, there is _no possible_ way you can do that much compression no matter how smart you are.

Comment: You can get down to 19 bytes for this exact example if you write a series of [varints](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding#varints). https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5160b46fc090773deb7896933ade8bc3 but it can as well get bigger than 7x4bytes a simple translation of int uses because this type of encoding is only small for positive numbers close to 0 but requires 5 bytes worst case per int.

Answer (score -1):

Apologies. I got some info wrong in my question as according to the [MIFARE Ultralight EV1 datasheet](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/MF0ULX1.pdf), the tag can hold **48 bytes** of user data - which is good news. (I had been a bit mislead by NXP's example app which is hardcoded to just use 16 bytes.)

Thank you for the helpful comments anyway. :-)

Comment: I'll leave the question as unresolved in case anyone wants to submit a proper answer to the original question anyway.