# JAVA Array of int to bytes array

Tags: java, arrays, byte

I have an int array `int[] stegoBitsArray = {0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1...}` I want each **8** bits converted to **byte** and added to byte array which i would later convert to char array because 01101100 is letter "l" and so on so ... So i tried using **ByteBuffer** but it throws me **BufferOverflowException** here's my code snippet:

```
 int[] stegoBitsArray = getStegoTextFromImage(stegoImage);
 ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(stegoBitsArray.length);
 for (int i = 0; i < stegoBitsArray.length; i++) {
    byteBuffer.putInt(stegoBitsArray[i]);
 }
```

Or it's more better to convert from int array to characters?

Comment: Is `0110110001100001` a **decimal number** that only contains 0/1 digits, or is it a **binary number** you wrote binary?

Comment: It's an array which contains value 0 or 1

Comment: If you want to convert 8 `int` values of `0` or `1` to a `byte`, then *you* have to do that using bit-manipulation, e.g. using the `<<` and `|` operators. There is no library method to do that for you, *you* have to write the code to do it. --- *Opinion:* What kind of idiotic method is `getStegoTextFromImage()`, returning *bits* as an `int[]`? *Yikes!*

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086054/how-to-convert-int-to-byte

Comment: How to convert 01101100 to it's decimal value 108 using bit manipulation ?

Answer (score 1):

To convert from binary to char you have to convert each 8 bit binary into byte and then you can cast from byte to char. Example:

```
byte b = Byte.parseByte("01100001", 2);
        System.out.println((char)b);
```

Prints

```
a
```

Answer (score 0):

How come you can have a value like 0110110001100001 in an integer array. Either it can be stored as a string or there is another way.

You can have an array of integer values something like int array = {123, 456, 333} etc then you can directly convert those integers to characters by looping on the array.

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
   char c = (char)array[i];  
   System.out.println(c);
}
```

Or if you want to convert integer to binary then Java supports in Integer class a method called toBinaryString. you can find a good resource for it [HERE](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/integer_tobinarystring.htm).

The combination of these two can lead you to your desired solution.