# converting the binary to decimal when binary is stored in an array

Tags: java

this is the code I have written but it gives incorrect answers and I can't figure out why

```
int decimal = 0;

int power= 0;

for(int i=0; i<binary.length; i++)
{
    int tmp = binary[i]%10;
    decimal+=tmp*Math.pow(2,power);
    power++
}

System.out.println(decimal);
```

Comment: what is `binary` ?

Comment: Could you give `binary` example input and expected output?

Comment: Binary is the array, it was previously initialized.

Comment: int[] binary = [1,0,0,1,1];   The expected output is 19 but I got 25

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For arbitrary sized `byte[]` you can use `BigInteger`.

```
public void test(String[] args) {
    byte[] b = new byte[] {1,2,3,4,5};
    BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(b);
    System.out.println(bi.toString(10));
}
```

If your array is an `int[]` then you can convert it - see [How to convert int[] to byte[]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1086054/823393).