# convert Object[] from stream to byte[]

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I try to filter a `byte[]`, I want to remove line breaks from the stream

```
byte[] data = "y\neahbabydoit\nsothisistheway\ntodoit".getBytes();
Object[] tmp = IntStream.range(0, data.length).mapToObj(idx -> Integer.valueOf(data[idx]).byteValue()).filter(i -> i != 10).toArray();
System.out.println("src:"+Arrays.toString(data));
System.out.println("dst:"+Arrays.toString(tmp));

//works not!!
byte[] dest = (Byte[]) tmp; //help me here
```

The result (as expected) works (so far) but I'm not able to convert the result (`Object[]`) in an easy way back (to `byte[]`)...

> src:[121, 10, 101, 97, 104, 98, ...
>   dst:[121, 101, 97, 104, 98, 97, ...

I know there are ways to solve this problem (see [How to convert int[] to byte[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086054/how-to-convert-int-to-byte)) but I want to do it in an easy (stream-like) way...

any news from java 8 or later?

Comment: keep in mind that `\n` is not the only line separator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Mureinik suggested, it is better to deal with characters rather than bytes, to answer your question, you can certainly use something like

```
Byte[] tmp = IntStream.range(0, data.length)
        .mapToObj(idx -> Integer.valueOf(data[idx]).byteValue())
        .filter(i -> i != 10)
        .toArray(Byte[]::new);
```

Comment: `.mapToObj(idx -> Integer.valueOf(data[idx]).byteValue())` will read a `byte` from the array, convert it to an `Integer` object, extract its value as `byte`, followed by boxing it into a `Byte`. It’s much simpler to use just `.mapToObj(idx -> data[idx])`, which reads a `byte` from the array and boxes it into a `Byte`.

Answer (score 2):

To save yourself the hassle of handling multi-byte characters, it may be a lot easier to just handle the stream of characters:

```
String result =
    data.chars()
        .filter(c -> c != '\n')
        .mapToObj(c -> String.valueOf((char) c))
        .collect(Collectors.joining());
```

Comment: Or just `data.replace("\n", "");`

Comment: @JacobG. better for the general task of “removing linebreaks” would be `data.replaceAll("\\R", "");`

Comment: @Holger Right but  `data.replace("\n", "")` will not work either as it is not a String but a `byte[]`. Or else : `new String(data, StandardCharsets.UTF_8).replace(...)`

Comment: @davidxxx if `data` was a `byte[]`, there was no `chars()` method either. Both, this answer and JacobG’s comment use the fact that the OP initially had a `String` before querying the byte array. The answer also recommends processing characters instead of bytes.

Comment: @ Holger Ah okiiiiiii. I didn't get it. It is clear now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Collecting to a byte array is not straight with Java 8.
But by using `ByteArrayOutputStream::new` as supplier in the collect operation you can.
It is a little more verbose because of the checked exception handling in the body lambda because of the combiner but it also has some advantages : it doesn't perform any boxing `byte` to `Byte` and it doesn't create unnecessary variables.

```
byte[] data = "y\neahbabydoit\nsothisistheway\ntodoit".getBytes();
byte[] dest = IntStream.range(0, data.length)
                       .map(i -> data[i])
                       .filter(i -> i != 10)
                       .collect(ByteArrayOutputStream::new, ByteArrayOutputStream::write, (bos1, bos2) -> {
                           try {
                               bos2.writeTo(bos1);
                           } catch (IOException e) {
                              throw new RuntimeException(e);
                           }
                       })
                       .toByteArray();

System.out.println("src:" + Arrays.toString(data));
System.out.println("dst:" + Arrays.toString(dest));
```

Output :

> src:[121, 10, 101, 97, 104, 98, 97, 98, 121, ...]
>
> dst:[121, 101, 97, 104, 98, 97, 98, 121,...]

Comment: You don’t need the type cast in `(bos, i) -> bos.write((byte) i)`, so you could even use `ByteArrayOutputStream::write`…